# Tween on a boolean property fails

Tags: three.js, tween.js

I am using TWEEN to create a series of animations on THREE.

According to the documentation, creating a tween on a non numeric property should change the property at the end of the transition time.

I am trying to animate the visible property of a material, but it won't work.

Of course I am not trying to change gradually from non-visible to visible; I just want to do it at some moment, but integrated in the tween sequence.

It is not working, and after a quick look at the code, it seems difficult to make it work.

Is there something that I missing in the TWEEN documentation. Or any workaround ?

> to
>   to ( props , duration , ease )
>   Queues a tween from the current values to the target properties. Set duration to 0 to jump to these value. Numeric properties will be tweened from their current value in the tween to the target value. Non-numeric properties will be set at the end of the specified duration.

[tween.js documentation](http://docs.createjs.jp/TweenJS_docs-0.2.0/Tween.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **.onComplete**

```
new TWEEN.Tween( cube.material ).to( { opacity: 0 }, 1000 )
.onUpdate(function(){
// do something if u want
})
.onComplete(function(){
// change boolean
console.log('DONE');
})
.start();
animate();
```

Don't forget to set the transparent flag of the material

Comment: Thank s a lot ! - I ended modifying the Tween source (had I know before!) .. If it is in the documentation, couldn't find it. But it's logical once you see the solution